# EXE Приложение на сервер

Tags: c#, сервер, клиент-сервер, браузер, exe

Можно ли установить winforms (C#) приложение на сервер что бы при переходе по ссылке пользователь не скачивал исполняемый файл а именно начинал работать с ним в браузере? Гугол уклончиво подсказывает что в принципе возможно, но как реализовать никакой конкретики.

Comment: а что Вы подразумеваете под работать с исполняемым файлом в браузере? почему не реализовать функционал *исполняемого* файла в *браузерном приложении*?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, браузер умеет работать только с текстовыми форматами (HTML, PDF, XML, etc) и плагинами. Все остальные файлы при запросе пользователя он скачивает на компьютер. Взаимодействовать с EXE можно, но для этого надо написать полноценный серверный вариант приложения, который будет работать поверх себя на том же HTML + сокеты для браузера.

Comment: А причём здесь winforms? Winforms не будет работать в браузере, хотя есть одно извращение. RDP over HTTP, но это та ещё хрень и настраивать замучаешься

Comment: @rdorn _Winforms не будет работать в браузере_ - А WPF приложение будет?

Comment: @Bald _почему не реализовать функционал исполняемого файла в браузерном приложении?_ Но ведь для этого нужно с нуля строить браузерное приложение, на  ASP.NET правильно ?

Comment: Взаимодействие с EXE сервер осуществляет через интерфейс CGI/FastCGI, но он просто запустит его и вернет результат работы браузеру. Интерактива не будет, для этого придется дописывать приложение под этот интерфейс и продумывать взаимодействие. Что гораздо сложнее выйдет, чем сделать все правильно. Вы можете вынести логику в отдельный проект, тогда на ASP.Net/ASP.Net MVC Вам останется только реализовать интерфейс и прикрепить к нему логику.

Comment: @AlexKrass т.е. правильно будет переписать приложение на ASP NET ?

Comment: Да, правильно будет создать приложение ASP.NET, которое для этого и предназначено. Вы в итоге сохраните больше нервных клеток, особенно если приложение развивается. Если Вы используете и онлайн и оффлайн версию приложения, то правильно будет создать решение (solution в VS), в котором вы логику своего приложения поместите в отдельную библиотеку. А рядом создадите два проекта, один из которых будет содержать UI WinForms, а второй будет содержать UI ASP.NET (и лучше всего ASP.NET MVC, если потянете).